# Message re-delivery and error handling in Message Listeners

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms

We have producer which is producing message at a rate faster than cosumer can consume. We are using Spring JMS integration as the consumer side technology stack. Currently we are using `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` mode.

In the `onMessage()` method of the listener, upon the receipt we are to planning submit the client side job to a job queue and return from the `onMessage()` method. This means if a) processing fails or b) our server goes down while processing there is no way for us recover.

We looked at the option of using `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE`, but this means acknowledging a message with higher timestamp automatically acknowledges all the messages with a less timestamp. This is clearly not desirable for us because a successful processing a message with newer timestamp no way means that all the messages with older timestamp are processed completely. In effect we are looking on per message acknowledgement. However, I read somewhere that this means there is some design flaw.

The other option is to use a `SessionAwareMessageListener` interface provided by Spring. The contract of using this interface says that if a `JMSException` is thrown from the `onMessage` the message will be redelivered. However, I was not completely sure how to use this for our purpose.

While I dig more myself into this, any help from you guys will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Session aware message has following onMessage prototype:

```
 onMessage(Message message, Session session)
```

Invoke session.recover() for the message redelivery. Upon session.recover() will send all the unacknowledged messages back to the jms destination.